# accessing tomcat manager gui not possible even after updating tomcat users and context xml files

Tags: fedora, tomcat8

I have a bsic tomacat 8.5 fresh setup, I went through documentaion as well as some threads here such as
[How to access tomcat manager gui from another machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/796960/how-to-access-tomcat-manager-gui-from-another-machine)
and others and all confirm  the same solution which is not working on my fedora box (of course every time I update a file I restart tomcat)
I have added necessary details in tomcat users file as follows

[image]

also updated context.xml to accept any IP and removed the CRSF as follows but still getting. Thanks for your help access denied

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, my bad, I was updating the wrong file